# Elixir - modifying values external to an anonymous function

Tags: elixir

First, I am absolutely sure that I'm going about this the wrong way as I'm still learning Elixir coming from Ruby...

I get a list of search results from youtube and am trying to extract the video with the most views.

```
# html is the contents of the search results page
metas = html |> Floki.find(".yt-lockup-meta-info > li")

counter = -1
index = -1
high_views = 0

Enum.each(metas, fn(li) ->
  counter = counter + 1
  text = Floki.text(li)
  case String.split(text, " ") do
    [count, "views"] ->
      views = String.to_integer(String.replace(count, ",", ""))
      IO.puts(">>> #{counter} - #{to_string(views)} views")
      if views > high_views do
        high_views = views
        index = counter
      end
    [age, time_measurement, "ago"] ->
      nil
  end
end)
```

`metas` is a list of `li` tuples, like this:

```
[{"li", [], ["2 years ago"]}, {"li", [], ["5,669,783 views"]},
 {"li", [], ["9 years ago"]}, {"li", [], ["17,136,804 views"]},
 ...
 {"li", [], ["1 year ago"]}, {"li", [], ["15,217 views"]},
 {"li", [], ["8 years ago"]}, {"li", [], ["909,053 views"]}]
```

This won't work because the anonymous function passed to `Enum.each` has its own scope and doesn't set the values for `index` and `high_views`.

Is there a way to pass values from the outside scope into the anonymous function? Or maybe a better question is, how should I go about doing this?

I intended to get it working and then refactor the code but I'm stuck. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8):

Elixir is immutable. The function is a closure, so the outside variables are visible in there, but you can't mutate them. You can only re-bind them, but that re-binding stays in the inner, anonymous function scope.

But the tools for what you're trying to do are all in the `Enum` module.

You're essentially looking for the index with the maximum views. Let's look through the [Enum functions](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#functions). `Enum.max_by/2` looks promising. It takes an enumerable and a function that returns a value we want to max. I'll pair it up with `Enum.with_index/1`, that takes a list, and wraps each element in a tuple with that element's index.

```
metas
|> Enum.with_index
|> Enum.max_by(fn {li, index} ->
  text = Floki.text(li)
  case String.split(text) do # (splits on whitespace by default)
    [count, "views"] ->
      views = count |> String.replace(",", "") |> String.to_integer
      IO.puts ">>> #{index} - #{views} views"
      views
    _ -> -1
  end
end)
```

The main difference to your implementation is that the inner function returns a value based on its arguments, instead of trying to mutate outside state.

I collapsed the "do nothing" case to a simple catch-all `_`, and return -1 on the assumption that youtube videos don't have negative view counts. A straight translation of your example would return zero here (the initial value of your `high_views`). That's probably safe, too.

Comment: Thanks @martin-svalin. I'm sure this would get me there as well. I think I just need to solve more problems with Elixir to get my head around it.

Comment: Of course, if you only want the element, and not the index, you can drop the `with_index` function, change the pattern on the anonymous function argument, and delete the `IO.puts` debug.

Answer (score 1):

As I surmised, I was indeed going about it all wrong. Here's how I ended up making this work:

```
defp extract_song_url_from_youtube_response(html = _) do
  sorted = html
  |> Floki.find(".yt-lockup-content")
  |> Enum.sort(fn(item1, item2) -> view_count(item1) > view_count(item2) end)

  [_, id] = Enum.at(sorted, 0)
  |> Floki.find("h3 > a")
  |> Floki.attribute("href")
  |> Enum.find(fn(x) -> x =~ "/watch" end)
  |> String.split("=")
  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" <> id
end

defp view_count(item) do
  meta = item |> Floki.find(".yt-lockup-meta-info > li")
  views = case Enum.at(meta, 1) do
    {"li", _, viewlist} ->
      parts = String.split(Enum.at(viewlist, 0), " ")
      String.to_integer(String.replace(Enum.at(parts, 0), ",", ""))
    nil ->
      # most likely a playlist
      0
  end
end
```

So, instead of trying to modify variables from outside the scope of the anonymous function, I stepped back up in the HTML hierarchy and sort on each `<div>` result based on the number of views the video has received.

Elixir is just amazing, once I can wrap my head around it and stop trying to force things to be like Ruby.

Comment: There's `Enum.sort_by` that would simplify your sorting to `Enum.sort_by(items, &view_count/1)`.